# CMSMS 500 Internal server error when trying to access .xlsx

Tags: php, excel, content-management-system, phpexcel

In my file manager i have 4 files.

```
test.php
data.inc.php
include.inc.php
sample.xlsx
```

test.php uses a get call to both data.inc.php and include.inc.php to read data from sample.xlsx.

When hosting these files from xampp they work perfectly but when hosting from CMSMS data.inc.php and include.inc.php both return "500 Internal server error"

Can anyone shed some light on what may be happening here i have not been able to uncover anything in my research.

EDIT i am using the following the user defined tag.

```
include 'uploads/Php/test.php';
include 'uploads/Php/include.inc.php';
include 'uploads/Php/data.inc.php';
```

Comment: What do the PHP error logs show?

Comment: Are you including an `.xlsx` file in your PHP code? If so, that'll be the problem as your server will be attempting to run the contents of `sample.xlsx` as PHP code.

Comment: Where can i find the error logs?

Comment: Depends on your system, but generally [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)

Comment: @JamieBicknell i am not including the .xlsx i am using $filename = 'uploads/Php/sample.xlsx'; to access it

Comment: The 4th line shows: `include 'uploads/Php/sample.xlsx';` so you are including it

Comment: nothing changes if i remove include 'uploads/Php/sample.xlsx';

Comment: Please post the error(s) from the PHP error log, and edit your question with those errors.

Comment: i used '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' to find the location of my error logs and the file path does not exist